# Patch persisting across multiple Django unit tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why two of my tests are conflicting. The patch in one test seems to be persisting to the other test. If I comment the patching test out, or just run the other test by itself there is no problem. My tests are:

```
class TestUrlRouting(TestCase):
    @patch('myapp.views.Home')
    def test_home_url_routes_to_home_view(self, mock_home_view):
        url = reverse('home')
        match = resolve(url)

        assert match.func == mock_home_view.as_view()


class TestHomeView(TestCase):
    def test_front_page_renders_home_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')
```

With the `Home` view being a `TemplateView`. The error I end up with is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/code/source/myapp/tests/test_views.py", line 11, in test_front_page_renders_home_template
    response = self.client.get('/')
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 503, in get
    **extra)
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 304, in get
    return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 380, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 467, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 242, in get_response
    response = self.apply_response_fixes(request, response)
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 305, in apply_response_fixes
    response = func(request, response)
  File "/path/to/code/virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/utils.py", line 17, in conditional_content_removal
    if 100 <= response.status_code < 200 or response.status_code in (204, 304):
TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= MagicMock()
```

Because I'm not doing anything special with the patch decorator, my guess is that it has something to do with how Django is setting things up. In particular, I found that patching `myapp.urls.Home` does not work. Instead I need to patch `myapp.views.Home`, despite the fact that the line under test is in `urls.py` as `url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),`. Any thoughts as to why this patch is persisting and how I can fix it? Thank you much!

**Update:**
The problem persists even when mocking `myapp.views.Home.as_view` instead of just `myapp.views.Home` (once again, note `views` is the option that correctly mocks and not `urls` for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

The call to `.as_view()` is made only once at import time (first time Django needs to visit "urls.py"), that's why it's "persisted".

IMO your first test case is just testing the Django framework and not anything in your own code except that the home view has a url name of "home". It isn't worth it to be that picky. You can easily cover that `reverse('home')` gets you to the right view in a another test case where you don't need to mock Django globals.